# overlapping alpha textures - shading problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency, shadows

I'm working on a bird that has an object particles system with transparent hair textures. When the textures are not overlapping is not a problem.

There are some weird artifacts going on as soon as they start overlapping.

I guess its shading the full mesh without the transparency in this case. Does anyone have a solution to this?

non overlapping feathers = good shading
 [image]

overlapping feathers = bad shading
 [image]

Comment: this is rendering in cycles btw